# Creating new activity, Intent error

Tags: java, android

```
String url = getOutputMediaFile().getName();
Intent i = new Intent(this, FotoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("yourkey", url);
startActivity(i);
```

I want to start new activity, and send string to it. But I have an error on`(this,FotoActivity.class);`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, for the rest of your life as a computer programmer, never say "you have an error" without stating the type of error. Please.

Comment: Please, for the rest of your life as a SO user, don't post a question about an error without posting a full stacktrace as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell without at least knowing what the error is, but my guess is that instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FotoActivity.class);
```

you should use either:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FotoActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, FotoActivity.class);
```

where "MyActivity" is the name of the Activity that you're creating the intent in.

Comment: Solving my problem, without knowing what it is. I am very new to this, and it is very confusing for me. THANK YOU.

Comment: When you ask a question on SO, remember to include the error message and stack trace - that makes it much easier for other members to figure out what actually went wrong, rather than guessing.  For Android, the stack trace is just the LogCat output - you can save that to a text file, and then just copy-paste the error into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FotoActivity.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FotoActivity.class);
```

I thik the problem is that you are using `this` as the context, but `this` is not a reference to that activity in that case. This is just speculation, as you haven't posted more code or a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have FotoActivity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name=".FotoActivity">
....
</activity>
```